# Cryptonote C++ compile error with invalid operands

Tags: c++, makefile, bitcoin

I am working with cryptonote repo for a project and am at the point where I need to compile the binaries.

When I run **make**, I get the following error:

```
/Documents/huntcoin/src/CryptoNoteCore/SwappedMap.h:185:14: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘const char [24]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
   std::count << "SwappedMap cache hits: " << m_cacheHits << ", misses: " << m_cacheMisses << " (" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << static_cast<double>(m_cacheMisses) / (m_cacheHits + m_cacheMisses) * 100 << "%)" << std::endl;
   ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am not super familiar with C++ and am sure it might be a simple parenthesis error, but it could be something more.

For some context, the previous make error I got was that `std::cout` was not defined, which I assumed was just a typo for count. Maybe that was wrong as well.

Any help with C++ or cryptonote would be much appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't see this before re-formatting: The error shows `std::count` not `std::cout`. Intention or accident? (Or copy/paste error?)

Comment: I would guess you have not included the iostream header, but as you haven't posted a complete example all I can do is guess. It is cout, not count.  Look carefully at this part: `<< static_cast<double>(m_cacheMisses) / (m_cacheHits + m_cacheMisses) * 100 << "%)"`, it sure looks like the ) is in the wrong place to me.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra `n` that is causing you trouble. The code should read:

```
std::cout << "SwappedMap c.....
```

`std::cout` is the default console output (**c**onsole **out**put) stream while `std::count` is not defined

The `std::cout` is defined in a header file `iostream` so all you need to do is put this line of code next to other `#include` statements at the top of your file:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Cheers